# Is Azure DNS redirecting all my traffic to HTTPS?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I just set up an Azure environment including Azure DNS. For one of my domain names, it appears to be redirecting all http traffic to HTTPS instead, even subdomain CNAME records that point to different domains. This is causing all kinds of certificate problems.

I know there is a way to do this with an application gateway, but I don't have an application gateway installed, no rewrite rules in a web.config file... for the CNAME records it shouldn't even be hitting my network, which is why I think this may be a DNS issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Redirection is a property of the HTTP protocol. Therefore, it's not a DNS issue.

Comment: DNS resolves fully qualified domain names to ip addresses. It has no bearing on the HTTP to HTTPS redirection that is occurring.

Comment: Also, it would help a lot to know the actual domain in order to investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was happening in the browser, not DNS, due to the strict-transport-security header including the "includeSubDomains" directive. I removed that directive and all works fine now.